# For which value of $e^x$ there is no $x$?

Tags: functions, exponential-function, examples-counterexamples

The function $y=f(x)=e^x$ is often called injective but non-surjective. It is easy to understand why is it injective. But I don't understand why is it non-surjective? For which value of $e^x$ there is no $x$?

Comment: For $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, $f(x)=e^x$ to be surjective, the range of $f(x)$ would need to be $\mathbb R$. But $e^x>0$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: For every _value of_ $e^x$, there is of course an $x$. It's the real numbers that aren't values of $e^x$ that make it not surjective.

Comment: Hint: for any $x$, $e^x>0$

Comment: Note that surjectivity completely depends on the codomain, and any function can be made surjective by setting the codomain to the range

Comment: @vrugtehagel A function can't "be made" surjective by setting the codomain, from any function you can construct a new one that is surjective, which matches the first one for every element in their domain.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD It's the same set of ordered pairs, only considered as a subset of a different Cartesian product.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma seeing a function as just the set consisting of pairs $(x,f(x))$, subset of **some** cartesian product leads to ill-defined notions of surjectivity, etc. I believe a more correct understand is to think of a function as a triple $(f, D, C)$, where $f\subset D\times C$. Clearly, under this definition, $(f, D, C)\neq (f, D, C')$ for $C\neq C'$.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD it's nicer to just define $\operatorname{dom(f)}$ and $\operatorname{rng}(f)$ from the set of pairs $f$, in the usual way. Surjectivity is then a void notion. Only injectivity is meaningful. This is very common in set theory. People have been brainwashed by category theory :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To discuss about surjective, we should specify the domain and codomain.

$$f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$ 
$$f(x)=\exp(x)$$
is not a surjection as it doesn't take negative value.

$$f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \{x| x>0, x \in \mathbb{R}\}$$

$$f(x)=\exp(x)$$ is a surjection as every positive number has a preimage.

Comment: +1. These types of questions are meaningless unless the function is completely described.

Answer (score 2):

The question you should have asked is: for which value $y$ there is no $x$, such that $y = e^x$. The answer: for all $y\leq 0$.

Comment: But isn't $Y=\{y\}$ made up of $\{e^x\}$ only? Where do I get the co-domain/rangle from? Do the codomain contain $y\leq 0$?

Comment: While I think it's implicit in this formulation, the statement is only true as written if we require $x$ to be real. Over the complex numbers, the only value which $e^x$ can't hit is $0$.

Comment: The definition of function consist of three parts: the domain, the codomain and the "rule". Usually, you take the domain as big as you can. You could take $f(x)= e^x$ as a function $f: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ or $f: [0, 2]\to \mathbb{R}$ or $f: \mathbb{R}\to (0, \infty)$. In the last case, $f$ would be surjective.

Comment: @Semiclassical Since SRS knows that $f(x) = e^x$ is injective, $\mathbb{C}$ cannot be $f$'s domain.

Comment: So you are specifying the codomain independent of what values $e^x$ can yield i.e., you specify it before you apply the "rule" not after. Is that correct?

Comment: We specify the domain, codomain, and the rule when we define the function, then we can discuss properties about injection, surjection, and bijection.

Comment: You may find the distinction between "codomain" and "range" useful. The codomain is specified more or less at the whim of the person defining the function, such as when we say $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. The range is the subset of the codomain that is actually witnessed by the function, which is $(0, \infty)$ in this case. You have a surjection when the codomain and the range are the same set.